# How to run command in foreground then send to background

Tags: linux, process

I need to run my application in foreground of linux terminal, send some commands to my program and then send program to background. I'm not really sure how to do that?

Comment: More detail is needed. Are you sending commands by typing in a terminal, or sending them from a separate process or parent process?

If you're just sending the commands via typing in the terminal and you are interacting with the program yourself, simply typing `ctrl-z` in most shells will send the program to background.

Comment: ctrl-z, not ctrl+z?

Comment: Same thing, just written a different way. Press `z` while holding `ctrl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution with the help of alienth and [this site](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/unix-background-job/) :

When you want to send some application which is running in foreground to background, you need to execute these two commands:

```
# [CTRL-Z]
[1]+  Stopped                 ./your_app

# bg
```

After this your process will continue its execution in background.